# Filter by list of objectid with Mongo 2.2 driver - C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, exception, filter

This is my code:

```
public IList<ConversationDescriptor> GetPersonalConversations(ObjectId author)
{
        var authorArray = new ObjectId[] { author };
        var filter = Builders<ConversationDto>.Filter.AnyEq("ParticipantsIds",authorArray)
                                _conversationStorage.Find(filter).ToListAsync().Result
}
```

And the `ConversationDto` object looks like:

```
public class ConversationDto : BaseEntity<ObjectId>
{
    public ObjectId CreatorId { get; set; }

    public IList<ObjectId> ParticipantsIds { get; set; }

    public BsonDateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    public BsonDateTime Timestamp { get; set; }

    public bool IsSystemMessage { get; set; }
}
```

`Builders<ConversationDto>.Filter.AnyEq("ParticipantsIds",authorArray)` - this filter makes that Exception:

```
System.AggregateException : One or more errors occurred.
  ----> System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type 'MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.ObjectIdSerializer' to type 'MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.IBsonSerializer`1[MongoDB.Bson.ObjectId[]]'.
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Thanks!